# Microsoft Sharepoint Powershell PNP Folder Add and Custom Columns

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to use Powershell to automate 3 processes,

I have a CSV file, with 3 columns, STUD_ID, NAME, Active, which has values in. The $NAME column will become the name of the folder I create in process 1.

Process 1)

```
# Set the SharePoint Online site URL
$siteUrl = "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/One-Education-Test"

# Connect to the SharePoint Online site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl 

# Path to the CSV file containing STUD_ID, NAME, and Active columns
$csvPath = "C:\Sources\SENDocumentsCSV\FileImportv3.csv"

# Read the CSV file
$foldersData = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

# Set the SharePoint library name
$libraryName = "Migrated Documents"
$customColumnName1 = "ActiveEHCP"
$customColumnName2 = "StudentID"

foreach ($row in $foldersData) {
    $folderName = $row.NAME

    # Create the folder in the library
    Add-PnPFolder -Name $folderName -Folder $libraryName

    # Retrieve the list item representing the newly created folder
    $folderItem = Get-PnPListItem -List $libraryName -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='Choice'>$folderName</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>" 

    # Set values for the custom columns
    $choiceActive = $row.Active
    $customSTUD_ID = $row.STUD_ID

    # Set custom column values
    $properties = @{
        $customColumnName1 = $choiceActive
        $customColumnName2 = $customSTUD_ID
    }

    # Update the list item with custom column values
    Set-PnPListItem -List $libraryName -Identity $folderItem.Id -Values $properties | Out-Null
}
```

This works fine, This will create the new folders based on the values for NAME in the CSV and append the corresponding STUD_ID and Active values for that row.

[FrontEnd of Sharepoint Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8kvl.png)

Process 2)
This is to create subfolders under each newly created. It will create the subfolders for each, but I cant et it to append the STUD_ID and Active values.

P.S. The backend column names are StudentID and ActiveEHCP

[Subfolder structure of subfolders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcgqB.png)

```
Function Create-SubfolderStructure {

    # Path to the CSV file containing STUD_ID, NAME, and Active columns
    $csvPath = "C:\Sources\SENDocumentsCSV\FileImportv3.csv"

    # Read the CSV file
    $foldersData = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

    # Loop through each row in the CSV file
    foreach ($row in $foldersData) {
        #Declare the Document Library
        $topLevelRoot = "Migrated Documents/$($row.NAME)"  ### No forward slash in the front ###
        Write-Host "Destination library is: " $topLevelRoot -f Cyan

        #array of folders
        $paths = @(
            "01. General communication",
            "02. Final EHCPs",
            "03. Statutory Assessment",
            "03. Statutory Assessment\a) Documents",
            "03. Statutory Assessment\b) Communication",
            "04. Reviews",
            "04. Reviews\a) Documents",
            "04. Reviews\b) Communication",
            "05. Panel documents and decisions",
            "06. Legal processes",
            "06. Legal processes\a) Tribunals",
            "06. Legal processes\b) Complaints, LGOs and JRs",
            "07. Phase transfers",
            "07. Phase transfers\a) Documents",
            "07. Phase transfers\b) Communication",
            "08. eStor",
            "09. N Drive",
            "10. One Education"
        )

        #Create the structure
        $paths | Foreach-Object {
            $split = $_ -Split "\\"
            $root = $null
            $previousRoot = $null    
            $i = 0
            $split | Foreach-Object {

                If ($i -ne 0) {
                    $previousRoot = $root
                    $root = ($root + ‘/’ + $_)
                    $current = $_
                    Write-Host "Sub-Folder Name: $current | Library: $previousRoot" -ForegroundColor Magenta 
                    Add-PnPFolder -Name $current -Folder $previousRoot -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                }
                Else {
                    $root = ($topLevelRoot + ‘/’ + $_)
                    $current = $_
                    Write-Host "Folder Name: $current | Library: $topLevelRoot" -ForegroundColor Cyan 
                    Add-PnPFolder -Name $current -Folder $topLevelRoot -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                }
                $i++
            }
        }
    }
}

Create-SubfolderStructure
```

Process 3)
Is an extension of me trying to append these values to the subfolders.

Any help would be appreciated. P.S I wouldn't mind it being a really simple error on my part, if that gets it working Ha

Writing to Host the variable values